# JS: Animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have the element .menu on my page, and one of my JS libraries has xslide attribute, which gives many options like draggable, overlay, radius etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.menu').xslide({
                draggable: true,
                overlay: 'rgba(255,30,100,1)',
                radius:0

            });
        });
```

The code above sets the properties in a fixed way, but I like to give them some smooth transition, so how do I use .animate thing by jQuery here? e.g I want radius to grow gradually into 20 in a few seconds when .menu clicked. So I believe my code should start like:

```
 $('.menu').click(function(){
```

Now what? When I try something like:

```
$(this).animate.xslide({radius:'20'},1000)
```

It does not work, can you help me? :) I'm sorry if I'm being annoying by asking these trivial things but I'm so new to it and I'm trying very hard. ^^

Comment: Have you tried looking at the jQuery's `.animate()` documentation? They have a lot of examples.

Comment: Can you link the documentation of the plugin? Because jQuery accepts CSS transitions and maybe the plugin adds some more support.

Comment: @BradM I'm trying to figure it out and when I can't I'm posting my question here.

Comment: @Niels this has nothing to do with the plugin, because my question is just about using .animate() function to change the value of an option specified in a  JS library.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery animate uses CSS styles to animate. If the plugin has an extension to animate radius, it is possible, otherwise animate will not work. Is the radius a CSS property?

If it would be a border-radius it will be something like:

```
$("#selector").animate({
    "border-radius" : "10px"
}, 500); // 500 MS
```

Comment: No, no. I don't know if it is CSS but it's just 'radius' and the first code I shared works perfectly fine, I just want that radius to animate and tried your code, it did not work. :/

Comment: $('.section').xslide({ radius:20 }); sets the radius 20, and gives me a good result, but this value should slowly grows up, not all of a sudden, that's the question

Comment: I know that's the question, but your not giving any info about the plugin. As I said a few times. jQuery Animate only allows CSS transitions except if the plugin made an extension. Give us more info so we can answer properly.